# How to create a scheduler for existing cart price rule in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, sales, schedule

I would like to create a programmatically scheduler for cart price rule/s and content changes in Magento 2 Enterprise. Can anyone guide me?